# AWS Athena - Connect from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

connecting/Running query in an aws athena via **lambda function is working fine**, but when i connect using lambda with vpc, it gives timeout error. please suggest a solution to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function is "in" a VPC, there are two options to enable access to Athena:

- Place your function in **private subnet** (public will not work), and setup **NAT gateway** in a public subnet with correct route tables. This way, your function will connect to Athena using NAT and subsequently, the internet.
- Create a **VPC interface endpoint** for Athena in your VPC. This does not require internet access, nor NAT. Subsequently you can **privately** connect to Athena without leaving AWS.